# Disable Zoom-In in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

We need a way to disable our users from zooming-in on our touch kiosks. We are using the most recent version of Google Chrome and when we have everything locked down, the user is not able to zoom out but is able to zoom in.

I know there used to be way to disable pinch zoom as a flag but that seems to no longer exist.

Has anyone successfully been able to accomplish this, preferably without an extension?

Thanks!

Comment: [Javascript - How to stop pinch zoom, multi touch input attacks?](//stackoverflow.com/q/37379694)

Comment: @wOxxOm that's a very useful thread, but I wish the top answer was verified and accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Disable pinch zoom works on my PC, when I run Chrome this way:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"  --start-fullscreen  --kiosk --disable-pinch  http://127.0.0.1:1000

OS: Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB
Chrome: Ver.: 65.0.3325.146  (64bit)

Comment: Finally someone answer works on same issue ( https://stackoverflow.com/q/49439378/285594 ) . Thanks!!